# SimplePath to omit certails paths based on vertex property

Tags: gremlin, amazon-neptune, tinkerpop3

I have a simple graph where I am trying to generate `path()` from given vertex

```
g.addV('ORG').as('1').
  property(single, 'orgId', 'f5c').addV('COMP').
    as('2').
  property(single, 'compId', 2112896).
  property(single, 'owner', 'def').addV('COMP').
    as('3').
  property(single, 'compId', 2100198).
  property(single, 'owner', 'def').addV('COMP').
    as('4').
  property(single, 'compId', 4007384).
  property(single, 'owner', 'def').addV('COMP').
    as('5').
  property(single, 'compId', 2106827).
  property(single, 'owner', 'abc').addV('COMP').
    as('6').
  property(single, 'compId', 2106829).
  property(single, 'owner', 'abc').addV('COMP').
    as('7').
  property(single, 'compId', 2104080).
  property(single, 'owner', 'abc').addV('COMP').
    as('8').
  property(single, 'compId', 2110851).
  property(single, 'owner', 'abc').addV('ORG').
    as('9').
  property(single, 'orgId', 28932).addE('edge').
  from('1').to('5').property('sub', '951a').
  addE('edge').from('1').to('2').
  property('sub', 5779).addE('edge').from('2').
  to('3').property('sub', 5779).addE('edge').
  from('3').to('4').property('sub', 5779).
  addE('edge').from('5').to('6').
  property('sub', '951a').addE('edge').
  from('6').to('7').property('sub', '951a').
  addE('edge').from('7').to('8').
  property('sub', '951a').addE('edge').
  from('4').to('9').property('sub', 1234).
  addE('edge').from('8').to('9').
  property('sub', 465474)
```

And when I am executing below query, I get 2 different paths which is fine

```
g.V().has("orgId", "f5c")
.repeat(bothE().otherV().simplePath())
.until(hasLabel("ORG")).path().by(valueMap())
```

If we see each of the vertex has a property called `owner`, and in my case I can have multiple owners
Question :
While getting the path I want to filter out all the paths where let's say `owner != def` which means it will only return the paths where owner is not def

I tried `hasNot()`

```
g.V().has("orgId", "f5c")
.repeat(bothE().otherV().hasNot("owner","def").simplePath())
.until(hasLabel("ORG")).path().by(valueMap())
```

But it didn't work.

Also why the below query is not giving any result

```
g.V().has("orgId", "f5c")
.repeat(bothE().otherV().has("compId", 2100198).simplePath())
.until(hasLabel("ORG")).path().by(valueMap())
```

I am trying to fetch the `paths()` which passes through a vertex which has property `compId` with value 2100198.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of reasons why your `hasNot` filter is not working here:

1. `hasNot()` checks for the existence of a property.  It does not evaluate the property value for equality.  Instead, you need to use `has(<key>,neq(<value>))`.
2. Your path contains vertices other than just the `COMP` vertices.  So when reaching the final `ORG` vertex in the path, you'll run into a situation where the evaluation of `has(<key>,neq(<value>))` fails because there's no `owner` property on the final `ORG` vertex.  I believe what you're looking for is:

```
g.V().
  has("orgId", "f5c").
  repeat(
    bothE().
    otherV().
    where(hasLabel('ORG').or().has("owner", neq("def"))).
    simplePath()).
    until(hasLabel("ORG")).
  path().by(valueMap())
```

Similar situation in your last query.  The `has("compId", 2100198)` will be evaluated on every element (vertex and edge) traversed after the starting vertex.  So if you wanted to check the entire path to see if a vertex was traversed with that specific property value, you would need to do something like the following:

```
g.V().has("orgId", "f5c")
.repeat(bothE().otherV().simplePath())
.until(hasLabel("ORG"))
.where(
    path().unfold().has("compId", 2100198))
.path().by(valueMap())
```